# No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() error Using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I am using OpenCV for `adaptiveThreshold`. My code for image processing using OpenCV is like this:

```
imageMat=new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, imageMat);
Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, imageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageMat, imageMat, new Size(3, 3), 0);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imageMat, imageMat, 255,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 5, 4);
```

But I am getting an error while declaring `Mat`:

```
No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:24)
        at com.example.pial_pc.instantbookreview.ImageCapture$3.onPictureTaken(ImageCapture.java:105)
```

As I'm new to OpenCV, I am not clearly understanding the error. The entire Java class where this code belongs is [here](http://pastebin.com/i9aKJAhK).

What should I do to eliminate the error?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I have successfully eliminate the error and my app does not crash while executing this line `imageMat=new Mat();`

The reason for the error is that Android calls the **"onCreate"** method before loading the OpenCV4Android library.So i have used Async Initialization of OpenCV using **OpenCVManager**. I have created **BaseLoaderCallback** before **onCreate** method. And inside that i have declared **new Mat()** like this:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i("OpenCV", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                imageMat=new Mat();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};
```

Then in **onResume()** i have checked if OpenCV library have been loaded and initialized  from within current application package or not. The codes are as follows:

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d("OpenCV", "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d("OpenCV", "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

And my error is gone. My full updated java class is [here](http://pastebin.com/7N9JFq9L).

**Reference links :**

1. [Async Initialization of OpenCV on Android using OpenCVManager](http://answers.opencv.org/question/10175/async-initialization-of-opencv-on-android-using-opencvmanager/)
2. [Tutorial1Activity.java](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/tutorial-1-camerapreview/src/org/opencv/samples/tutorial1/Tutorial1Activity.java)

Comment: Nice solution...helped me a lot

Comment: i'm really in need of help with this question, can you help me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed

Comment: InitDebug will always work even in a release build? How do we load/init the library when on release?

Answer (score 21):

Initialize openCV library in your activity
add this code before onCreate() method

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
    }
}
```

add this lib in your project : https://github.com/hschott/Camdroid

Answer (score 16):

I put this line on onCreate method and make sure openCvManager is installed. This worked fine for me.

`OpenCVLoader.initDebug();`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you are forgetting to include the openCV library.

Include

```
static { 
     System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
}
```

for OpenCV version 3 you should instead add:

```
static { 
     System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
}
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: This worked with me. Thanks Siddharth Bhatheja!

Comment: Should I use this code in my activity class ? And what is the equivalent code for Kotlin ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this to resolve error.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        Mat m;
        Mat grayM;
        ImageView imageView;
        public MainActivity()
        {
            if (!OpenCVLoader.InitDebug())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("GG");
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Make sure when linking the module dependency copy the file in native/libs opencv to a jniLibs directory in your project then set the following in your build.gradle(app) the build.

```kotlin
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni {
                srcDirs 'src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs'
            }
        }
    }
```

After that add this to your main activity

```kotlin
OpenCVLoader.initDebug()
```