# Convert from bitmap rgb_565 to Mat

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap, mat

I am using Android Intent to take a photo.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

This opens the native camera and i can take a picture.
In the Activity where the picture is returned to , in the onActivityResult method , I can get a hold of the returned Bitmap like so.

```
if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

I then wish to convert this to a Mat to do some openCV image processing. 
I am attempting to convert like this.

```
Mat src = new Mat(imageBitmap.getHeight(), imageBitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(imageBitmap, src);
```

The line above causes a crash with the following stack trace .

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.i330155.testing123, PID: 16349
              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__III)
                  at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
                  at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:37)
                  at com.example.testing123.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:48)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7022)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4248)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4295)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1583)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

After searching i found the following post. 
     http://answers.opencv.org/question/52722/what-is-the-correct-way-to-convert-a-mat-to-a-bitmap/

Which says that.

```
mat is a valid input Mat object of the types 'CV_8UC1', 'CV_8UC3' or 'CV_8UC4'.
bmp is a valid Bitmap object of the same size as the Mat and of type 'ARGB_8888' or 'RGB_565'.
```

As you can see in the constructor for the Mat I supply these args. 
I have checked the config of the imageBitmap  , which confirms that it is indeed 
a 'RGB_565'.

What am i missing here? I dont understand why this does not work. 
Thanks in advance.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   Button button ;
   ImageView mImageView ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture) ;
        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView) ;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        Bitmap.Config config = imageBitmap.getConfig();
        //this is throwing error
        Mat src = new Mat(imageBitmap.getHeight(), imageBitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(imageBitmap, src);

        Imgproc.Canny(src, src, 10, 100);
        Bitmap edgeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       // Utils.matToBitmap(dest, edgeBitmap);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

}

When debugging this method call : 
    Mat src = new Mat(imageBitmap.getHeight(), imageBitmap.getWidth(), 
    CvType.CV_8UC3);

calls another method

```
 nativeObj = n_Mat(rows, cols, type);
```

this n_Mat is declared like so.

```
   // C++: Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type)
   private static native long n_Mat(int rows, int cols, int type);
```

and is highlighted in red.

Comment: `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);` This tells nothing.  Please show complete intent code.

Comment: `I have checked the config of the imageBitmap , which confirms that it is indeed a 'RGB_565'. ` Which i dont believe. Please post your code too.

Comment: that action is function correctly , i can get a handle on the returned bitmap , and display it. 

after more debugging the : 
at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:37) is not compiled correctly , all native methods in this class are highlighted in red

Comment: I think the code above will function if i can figure out why this class does not compile

Comment: It's unclear where you are talking about. And if you dont want to show the requested code...

Comment: I am now unable to edit the question above  ,to add the complete code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164753/discussion-between-broomer-and-greenapps).

Comment: `Bitmap.Config config = imageBitmap.getConfig();` Please show the code with which you conclude that it is 565.

Comment: I simply placed a break point and inspected the config.

Comment: Then what kind of device do you use? Here i get ARGB_8888.

Comment: I use a onePlus 3T  , from my understanding a type of  ARGB_8888 is also accepted by this constructor. 

I have added more information about what i found when debugging.
I feel the code above is correct , and this is a different issue. 

The stack trace says  No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__III) 

and indeed the n_Mat(int ,int, int) is underlined with red

Comment: With the code above are you able to create a Mat object?

Comment: I did not try it. I only checked the config. So you are saying that your code does not compile? Or what do you mean with underlined red?

Comment: yes by underlined with red i mean not compiling. However that code wa shipped with opencv4android

Comment: Reports native method declarations in Java where no corresponding JNI function is found in the project.

Answer (score 1):

The application no longer crashes and functions as expected.

This post covers it quite well. 
    [No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() error Using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090838/no-implementation-found-for-long-)
    org-opencv-core-mat-n-mat-error-using-opencv