# No implementation found for void org.opencv.core.Core.rotate_0

Tags: java, maven, opencv, android

I build the OpenCVLib taught by [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c) and done necessarily stuff in the OpenCVLib to call [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090838/no-implementation-found-for-long-org-opencv-core-mat-n-mat-error-using-opencv/56864883?noredirect=1#comment100278686_56864883) in mavenLocal.

Then I publish it as mavenLocal but I didn't take the libs to put into my app folder as I already have mavenLocal.

I have tried converting bitmap to mat without a problem.

But I can't rotate the Mat.

```java
public Bitmap rotateMat(Bitmap bitmap, int i){
        Mat mat = helper.bitmapToMat(bitmap);
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                Core.rotate(mat, mat, 0);
                break;
            case 2:
                Core.rotate(mat, mat, 2);
                break;
            case 3:
                Core.rotate(mat, mat, 1);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("================= No Rotation");
        }
        return helper.matToBitmap(mat);
    }
```

```java
E/zygote64: No implementation found for void org.opencv.core.Core.rotate_0(long, long, int) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Core_rotate_10 and Java_org_opencv_core_Core_rotate_10__JJI)
```

This is cause by `Core.rotate(mat, mat, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

1. Add the libs to OpenCV library and rename it to jniLibs
2. Lastly, publish it as MavenLocal