# Android, opencv - No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() when trying to initialize Mat

Tags: java, android, opencv, gradle, dependencies

I want to do some things using OpenCV and I'm trying to create `Mat` object:

```
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
...
Mat imageMat = new Mat(CvType.CV_8U);
```

On this line I get the error:

```
2021-04-28 15:13:44.657 23613-23613/xxxx.yyyy E/art: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)
2021-04-28 15:13:44.676 23613-23613/xxxx.yyyy D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-04-28 15:13:44.686 23613-23613/xxxx.yyyy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxxx.yyyy, PID: 23613
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:26)
        at org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f.<init>(MatOfPoint2f.java:12)
        at xxxx.yyyy.Utils.quadrilateralToRect(Utils.java:77)
        at xxxx.yyyy.activities.CropActivity$1.onClick(CropActivity.java:74)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

I have OpenCV as separate module in my android project and have imported it into my main module by adding `implementation project(path: ':OpenCV')` in its build.gradle in `dependencies` section.

I have seen one [simillar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090838/no-implementation-found-for-long-org-opencv-core-mat-n-mat-error-using-opencv) question but it is answered with using OpenCvManager which I wouldn't like to use in my project. If I'm getting right, my users will be forced to install this manager separately before using my app, right? It is disgousting.

**UPD 1**

I've added

```
static {
        Log.d(TAG, "OPENCV INITIALIZATION " + (OpenCVLoader.initDebug() ? "SUCCEEDED" : "FAILED"));
    }
```

in my `MainActivity.java`. It prints "SUCCEEDED" but the error hasn't gone. However, it changed:

```
2021-04-28 21:09:47.798 22656-22656/xxxx.yyyy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxxx.yyyy, PID: 22656
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Native object address is NULL
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:14)
        at xxxx.yyyy.Utils.quadrilateralToRect(Utils.java:94)
        at xxxx.yyyy.activities.CropActivity$1.onClick(CropActivity.java:74)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

**UPD 2**

Oops error in UPD 1 was because of argument in `new Mat()`. With no args there is no errors yet. Investigation continues.

Comment: https://github.com/alcarazolabs/surflaweb-scripts/blob/main/4-Manual%20para%20agregar%20opencv%20a%20android%20studio%202021%20v2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I have found the solution **(worked for OpenCV 3)**. It was needed to copy folder `sdk\native\libs` from downloaded SDK into the project's root and name it `jniLibs`. Each of its forders has single file named `libopencv_java3.so`, as follows:

[image: jniLibs in project structure]

Also, probably, it is useful to add this code to your main activity:

```
static {
    if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OPENCV INITIALIZATION SUCCEEDED");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OPENCV INITIALIZATION FAILED BUT TRYING TO RELOAD");
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
    }
}
```

**Bad side:** these files add 80 Mb to your APK after build. Better solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It is suggested to use CMake to link the SDK rather than copying the compiled file.

You can add OpenCV_DIR cmake argument in your application build.gradle under
android > defaultConfig > externalNativeBuild > cmake

```
arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=" + file('../sdk').absolutePath + "/native/jni",
        "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
```

Then use find_package to install OpenCV in CMake

```
set(ANDROID_OPENCV_COMPONENTS "opencv_java" CACHE STRING "")
message(STATUS "ANDROID_ABI=${ANDROID_ABI}")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${ANDROID_OPENCV_COMPONENTS})
```